# VC++ 2010 exclude library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

A project I'm building is attempting to include a library, but for the life of me I can't find out the call to include it is coming from. It's trying to include atlthunk.lib, which is supposed to be included through a #pragma comment in atlbase.h, but there's no such comment in my atlbase.h.

I read about someone else who had this problem, but circumvented it by "excluding the lib forcefully". I realise this isn't a stable solution, but could someone tell me how one goes about forcefully excluding a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a project setting under

Linker/Input - Ignore Specific Default Libraries

Put the library to ignore there.

Here is a screenshot to help you along:

[image]